# Convert VARBINARY to Int or BigInt

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2016

My question is very simple and I understand that few Old days DB design is not good as we espect these days.

My legacy table does not have Primary key to perform Delta load. Hence, I'm trying to use Hashing concept to create Unique key. As "HASHBYTES" return VarBinary and I can not use VarBinary type as 
primay key (not sure about this)

Ref URL on MSDN: 
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/94231bb4-ccab-4626-a9fb-325264bb883f/can-varbinary700-column-be-used-as-primary-key?forum=transactsql

hence, I'm converting this to INT or BigInt. The problem is it gives both negative as well as positive value(due to the range).

My Question is:
How can I convert VARBINARY(100) type to integer or BigInt (+ve value) and Set this as a Primary key in one of my table?

Edit Note:

I tried to use VARBINARY as Primary key for Delta load in SSIS Lookup task. I got the error:

> "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK__DMIN__607056C02FB7E7DE'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.DMIN_'. The duplicate key value is (0x00001195764c40525bcaf6baa922091696cd8886).".

However, when I checked for duplicate key from the table. Table does not have duplicate key. Then why this error is showing up?

Please note that, the 1st time of SSIS execution worked fine. However, it shows error during 2nd execution [during "**lookup match output**"].

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: With `INT`, the chance for collisions is substantial -- even a few ten thousand rows will have a high chance to collide. Even `BIGINT` will quickly break down if your table has millions of rows. Is there any reason you can't simply use an int/bigint identity for the primary key (if you must have a key), and use an index on the full hash value to check if your row is present?

Comment: Why can't you use varbinary(100) as the PK?

Comment: Most likely the second execution fails because the row you're trying to import is actually already there. Double check how you're making SSIS exclude rows that already exist. SSIS has its own rules for comparing values that don't necessarily match up with SQL Server's. Note also that you should insert the rows that *don't* match the lookup output (i.e. *not* present), so make sure you've hooked up the right outputs to the right inputs.

Answer (score 0):

In projects I've worked on before we've always used GUIDs as our primary keys, utilising the unique identifier type in SQL Server.

The main problem with this however, is that using a uniqueidentifier type as your clustered index can degrade the performance of your database after some time, so recently we've taken the following approach (based on [this article)](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/ever-increasing-clustering-key-the-clustered-index-debate-again/):

Create column: guid, uniqueidentifier, nonnull, default value newsequentialid(), PK
Create column: id, bigint, nonnull, identity(1,1)

Create a non clustered index on the guid column, unique
Create a clustered index on the id column, unique

That way when you insert into this new table, you don't have to worry about the keys or identities.

If you need some form of reference between the old database and the new and you CAN modify the structure of the old database, you can create a uniqueidentifier column in that (or char(36) if it doesn't support uniqueidentifier) and assign a guid to each of those and THEN create an additional uniqueidentifier column in the new database so you have that reference and insert that value into it. If that makes sense.